# What OOD pattern to use when it looks like you need to access a subclass method via a superclass reference?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm working on a problem similar to this: there are Offices and Districts.  Some, but not all, Offices have sales information.  Some, but not all, Districts have sales information.  Offices that have sales information are always in Districts that have sales information, and they require that district sales information.  Offices that don't have sales information, don't care what kind of district they are in.  So, how does one best model this in object oriented design?

Obviously, we have `Office` and `District` classes, and there is a relationship between the two.  The most straightforward implementation is to include sales information members directly in these classes and those members are null when sales information isn't present.  However, it seems more OO to me to partition out instances with sales information as instances of `SalesOffice` and `SalesDistrict` and so you would have something like this:

```
District <-------- Office
    ^                 ^
    |                 |
SalesDistrict      SalesOffice
  * GetSalesInfo     * GetSalesInfo
                     * PrintSalesInfo()
```

Here's the rub: SalesOffice.PrintSalesInfo needs to call GeSalesInfo of both SalesOffice and SalesDistrict, and casting District to SalesDistrict just seems like a bad idea.

There must be a commonly used design pattern that can be applied here so that:

1. An `Office` can always know what `District` it belongs to, regardless of what kind of district it is.
2. A subset of offices and districts have sales information.
3. An `Office` with sales information can access the sales information of the `District` it belongs to.

Suggestions?  Should I just forget about inheritance and create an `IsSalesType` flag for both `Office` and `District` or is there a better way?

[**Edit**: Note that the sales information returned by `District` and `Office` are not the same type of information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation, it looks like the `SalesDistrict` and `SalesOffice` are just holders to the sales data and do not add any extra behavior themselves. I think using inheritance to represent this is not a good idea.

I think having the sales information as instance variable in District/Office is a better way to it. However, you do not need to have an `isSalesType` boolean flag to represent this.

If you are using Java 8, `Optional` data type is a perfect fit here. This is used to represent data that can be either present or absent. In this case, your District class would look like:

```
class District {
    ...
    Optional<SalesInfo> salesInfo;
    ...
}
```

Whenever you need to use sales info, wrap it up using:

```
if(salesInfo.isPresent()) {
    ...
}
```

To instantiate a sales info object, use:

```
Optional.of(new SalesInfo(..));
```

You can use `Optional.empty()` to instantiate it to an empty value in non-sales District/Office classes.

EDIT:

Even if there is small amount of behavior like you said about printing sales information, I would still go ahead with the above implementation, because it is conceptually simpler to understand. Inside the `printSalesInfo` method of the `Office` class, you just need to do:

```
if(district.getSalesInfo().isPresent()) district.getSalesInfo().get().printSalesInfo();
```

However, if you still want to avoid the checks altogether, here is my shot at it:

```
class Office {
    private District district;
    // constructor
    public Office(District district) {
        this.district = district;
    }
}

class SalesOffice extends Office {
    private SalesDistrict district;
    private SalesInfo salesInfo;

    public SalesOffice(SalesDistrict district) {
        super(district);
        this.district = district;
    }

    public void printSalesInfo() {
        salesInfo.print();
        district.printSalesInfo();
    }
}

class District {
    ....
}

class SalesDistrict extends District {
    private SalesInfo salesInfo;
    public void printSalesInfo() {
        salesInfo.print();
    }
}
```

We are basically retaining a reference to `SalesDistrict` object in the `SalesOffice` class although the parent class already has a reference. Note that we are not duplicating the memory used by the object. We are only keeping an extra reference. Of course, this does not allow you to construct a sales office object with a non-sales district, but that is one of your assumptions anyway.

Comment: I agree that inheritance is probably not the way to go, hence the question.  What if there is a small amount of behaviour?  I just threw in PrintSalesInfo in my question to try to demonstrate that.  Calling PrintSalesInfo would be invalid if it wasn't an office that handled sales, and so my motivation was to exclude that behaviour for offices that aren't sales offices, eliminating the need for checking for the existence of sales info since it would always be present for "SalesOffice" objects.  I guess this checking is trivial, but it might start to look strange if many such methods existed.

Comment: I altered the answer providing an option that doesn't involve using `Optional` or `null`. That said, if it's just about printing stuff, I'd still go ahead with the original one, because it is simpler and clearer to understand for someone reading the code.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I instinctively rejected having a reference in both the superclass and the subclass, but thinking about it now, there's nothing wrong with that.  A great solution when referencing across inheritance trees.  In my particular case, I discovered that I can have default behaviour for sales info and so I'm going to use the Null Object pattern instead of using inheritance to keep it simple.  Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should not separate the office or district into classes having sales and classes lacking them.  Their relationship to sales is "has a", not "is a".  Just define a separate sales object, give office and district each a reference to a sales object, and give the sales office a reference to its parent district.  That way the sales things have only one interface regardless of whether they're in a district or an office.

Comment: I didn't convey it explicitly, but the sales info for office and district are not the same type of info.  I just added a note to the question.

Comment: Then define an interface or abstract base class for the common subset.